# ZF2 - Confused about managers

Tags: zend-framework2

In ZF2 there appear to be a lot of "managers" without much documentation on them, e.g. the view manager, input filter manager, etc.  Is the purpose of these managers dependency injection?  How are they related to the service manager (are they services themselves?)? Are they recommended only for internal use or is the lack of documentation on them just a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service managers exist to make inversion of control easier.

The "main" service manager as well as each specialized manager (input, view helper, controller plugin, etc) is extended from Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceMananger.

I believe the specialized managers are there to group functionality (all view helpers registered with view helper manager) and also avoid key collisions.

If you're using ZF2 MVC, you will most certainly end up using these service managers. Examples would be if you want to register your own view helper or your own controller plugin.